# childNodes specific values forgotten after insertBefore

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a simple script that add extra form fields when needed by the user: the html part consist of a first section where I define a form field pattern and a second part, ready for the insertion of the pattern.

```
<div id="readroot" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" value="test" id="name" name="name">
</div>

<form method="post" action="index.php">

    <span id="writeroot"></span>

    <a href=# onclick="moreFields();">Add record</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />

</form>
```

The javascript part would have to exactly replicate the "readroot" div just before the "writeroot" span. It replicates everything, indeed, except the "name", "id", value" of the input fields (or, maybe, I'm not able to handle them). I also tried putting an onclick to detect the field name after it's been "placed", but it doesn't return the correct name!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var counter = 0;
  window.onload = moreFields();

  function moreFields() {
     counter++;
     var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
     newFields.id = 'baba';
     newFields.style.display = 'block';
     var newField = newFields.childNodes;
     for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name;
        if (theName)
           newField[i].name = theName + counter;
           newField[i].onclick = alert(this.name);
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    inserted = insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
    }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anyhthing in your javascript console? the whole changing names/ids on the fly in your code looks rather suspect, and I'm guessing an error is killing your script.

Comment: Don't all your added fields have the same div id : 'baba'? Also the input elemnts will all have the id 'name' (you don't change them).

Comment: I left a tab during the insertion here on stackoverflow, so one line was hidden, now the name would change, but it doesn't! (and the alert pop out at window.onload and not onclick!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are setting the `click` event handle the wrong way. You are calling `alert` immediately  and in this context , `this` will refer to the `window` object.

It should be:

```
newField[i].onclick = function() {alert(this.name);};
```

Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2KSds/

[image: DOM]

The `name` of the input field is correctly changed and the id is there. If you add the element more that one time you also have to change the `baba` id and the `name` id to something unique.

---

The question is whether you need the IDs at all. Do you have to uniquely identify the fields? Using classes might be sufficient. Something like:

```
<div id="readroot" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" value="test" name="name" class="inputClass">
</div>
```

and

```
var readroot = document.getElementById('readroot'),
    writeroot = document.getElementById('writeroot');

function moreFields() {
     counter++;
     var newFields = readroot.cloneNode(true);
     newFields.removeAttribute('id');
     newFields.className += 'fieldContainer';

     var newFields = newFields.childNodes;
     for (var i = 0, l = newField.length; i < l; i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name;
        if (theName) {
           newField[i].name = theName + counter;
        }
        newField[i].onclick = function() {alert(this.name);}
     }
     inserted = writeroot.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,writeroot);
}
```

You can then control the visibility through setting CSS rules for `.fieldContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work :

```
  var counter = 0;
  window.onload = moreFields();

  function moreFields() {
     counter++;
     var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
     newFields.id = 'baba' + counter;
     newFields.style.display = 'block';
     var newField = newFields.childNodes;
     for (var theName, i = newField.length; i--;) {
        if (theName = newField[i].name) {
           newField[i].name = theName + counter;
           newField[i].onclick = confirm (newField[i].name);
        }   
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    inserted = insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
    }
```

I added the counter to the newFields id and in the alert (changed to confirm) you used this instead of newfields.

Comment: The `click` handler is still wrong. You have to assign a function to `onclick`. `confirm` does not return a function.